# How to include a string resource in XML format accessible in every *.cs file?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, dot42

As my title says, how do I include a resource string in XML format that I can access by its id? This id is auto generated in dot42 but I can't find any teachings in Google.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file strings.xml with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="firstName">MisterFive</string>
</resources>
```

Include it in your project and set the Build Action property to 'ValuesResource'.

If you open R.cs (inside properties folder), you will see that the following code is generated:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This file is automatically generated by dot42
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace dot42Application2
{
  using System;

  public sealed class R
  {
    public sealed class Strings
    {
      public const int firstName = 0x7f040000;
    }
  }
}
```

You can access your string resource from C# like this:

```
string firstName = GetString(R.Strings.firstName);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I made an answer too but this one is different(somewhat manually) so I think it could help someone too :)

Answer (score 0):

NM! Just figure it out again.

For anyone who came into this problem, just go to:

```
Solution Explorer > Project(Right Click) > Add > New Item > Dot42 > Android > String table resource > Build (Press F7) > Done!
```